# using $wpdb to get custom post type with term array

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get the ranking the number of meta_key at specific custom post type.
But I'm not great at SQL so therefor not great with using $wpdb.

For example, if I write something like this,

```
<?php 
$tarms = array( ‘sweet, sour’ );
echo get_count_ranking( $tarms );
?>
```

Then I would like to display rankings from comment("custom post of reply") of "custom post of fluits" with "term of sweet" and "term of sour" in order of "meta_key of count".

Here is my code:

```
function get_count_ranking( $tarms ){
    global $wpdb;   
    $counts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT p.post_author AS user_id, sum(m.meta_value) AS SumUser
        FROM  $wpdb->posts AS p, $wpdb->postmeta AS m
        WHERE p.ID = m.post_ID
        AND p.ID IN ( 
            SELECT tr.object_id 
            FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr, $wpdb->posts AS p, $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt
            WHERE p.post_type = 'reply'
            AND tt.term_id = %s
            AND p.id = tr.object_id 
            AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
        )
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND m.meta_key = 'count'
        GROUP BY p.post_author
        ORDER BY m.meta_value DESC LIMIT 10
    ", $tarms ) );          
    $result = '';
    foreach ( $counts as $count ) {
        $result .= '<li><img>'.get_avatar($count->user_id, 30).'<span></span></li>';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I am sorry that my English is so bad.
So I attach that image for your reference.
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CDHX.jpg)

--

Updated code:

```
function get_count_ranking( $tarms ){
    $customPostArg = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type'      => 'fluits',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taste-tag',
                'field'    => 'slug', 
                'terms'    => $tarms 
            )
        )
    );
    $array_with_post_ids = get_posts($customPostArg);

    $argsp = array(
        'post__in' => $array_with_post_ids
    );
    $commentsp = get_comments( $argsp );

    $needed_data_array = array();
    foreach ($comments as $key => $comment) {
        $ranking = get_comment_meta($comment->ID, 'count', $return_single_value = true);
        $author_id = $comment->user_id;

        // make sure we have an author id
        if($author_id) {
            $needed_data_array[$author_id][] = $ranking; 
        }
    }
}

$tarms = array( ‘sweet, sour’ );
echo get_count_ranking( $tarms );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `$wpdb` for this.
Also, it looks like you save rankings to a POST meta field, I would use a comment meta field.

> Please NOTE, i'm not going to help you write everything, but here are
>   some pointers how I would accomplish this.

- Register the custom post types with comment capability.
- Extend the add comment to include a ranking setter. Save this ranking data in a [comment_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta) field. Now the comment and ranking meta are linked. When you remove the comment, the ranking meta data is also removed from the DB.

Now post comments and rankings are saved.

**Collecting data**

WP has a [`get_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function, this function accepts many arguments. Sadly, I miss an argument to get comments from posts with a certain taxonomy. So we have to collect all the posts first:

- Collect all the posts with 'sweet' and/or 'sour' taxonomy, use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).
- Build an array with post id's.
- Use `get_comments()` to get all comments connected to the posts.

Example:

```
$args = array(
  'post__in' => $array_with_post_ids, 
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

Now you have all the comments you need for creating overviews, I would loop (iterate) through them and build an array with author_names and their rankings.

Example:

```
$needed_data_array = array();
foreach ($comments as $key => $comment) {
  $ranking = get_comment_meta($comment->ID, 'ranking_meta_key', $return_single_value = true);
  $author_id = $comment->user_id;

  // make sure we have an author id
  if($author_id) {
    $needed_data_array[$author_id][] = $ranking; 
  }
}

//
// Now the $needed_data_array holds all authors
// and their post rankings, you can count them 
// to get ranking totals for each comment-author.
//
```

Comment: Sorry, "get_comments()" can not be used for this requirement.

Comment: These comments are post types "reply", which is what is created by BBpress.

Comment: That BBpress info would have been great from the start :-P.....
Use `get_posts()` to collect the data you want. See link in my answer.

Comment: I var_dump the following code, but only "array(0) { }" was displayed.
After all, is not it possible to use "get_comments()" for BBPress's "reply"?

Comment: $array_with_post_ids = array( '492, 465' );
$args = array(
  'post__in' => $array_with_post_ids, 
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
var_dump($comments);

Comment: Oh, sorry.I forgot "get_post". I'll try now.

Comment: I added some information.Please have a look at "Updated code"